How to debug emacs with the -q flag if using emacsclient (exwm)?
I start my desktop using .xinitrc:
emacs --daemon -f exwm-enable
exec emacsclient -c

Now I'm required to run emacs -q in order to debug image display issues
How should I achieve that since emacsclient doesn't provide any init file skip mechanism?

You add the -q to the emacs --daemon ... invocation. If you start the emacs daemon without -q then it loads your init file, so emacsclient cannot do anything at that point: it cannot make emacs unload the file.

Did you see this answer? Did it work for you? Please don't leave old questions orphaned: review and either accept an answer or respond with any problems.
